# Design patterns/tools for a HTML app with a reactive layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

We're building a website with app versions that will (initially) be HTML driven. 
We want the same document to be rendered with varying layouts and styles depending on: client device/browser, width/height, PPI, aspect ratios.

e.g. Check out SquareSpace and make your browser smaller/bigger, wider/taller: http://www.squarespace.com/

What's a good set of tools or design patterns for constructing a reactive web client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) its a good option and you can use [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) too.

Answer (score 2):

Try bootstrap. They designed their styling for things such as what you are doing. Bootstrap offers tools such as interactive layout across all platforms and screen sizes - find more info on their website...http://getbootstrap.com/ Hope this helps!